# Set background image in xfce4 (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: xfce, desktop-background

I'm trying to do something that I *think* should be ridiculously simple, and I know it's something I've done probably hundreds of times over the past 30 years. (Not kidding). I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 with xfce4 as my desktop.

I've tried using the xfce4 "Desktop" UI tool, but it won't let me select any of my own `.jpg` files (or any `.jpg` files at all).

I've tried running `xloadimage` or `xsetbg`, and they run without complaint but they do not affect the screen background.

I've tried loading the image in `geeqie` and asking it to set the image as the background image.

I am not running Nautilus, so I know it's not taking over my background (currently it's the blue xfce4 background with the black mouse in the middle).

What is it that I have to do to set the background image? I mean, isn't that among the simplest things in the universe to want to do?

Comment: The GUI for XFCE's Settings -> Desktop -> Background tab should work - you're saying it doesn't? And by "any of my own .jpg files," do you mean it won't select a random file, you've put them in the right folder already & they're readable? Or it's just the jpg's that are a problem?

Comment: Yes, I'm saying it doesn't. It will not let me select any image file (like, any of the thousands of `.jpg` files I've got on my system). I can navigate all over the place and no `.jpg` file is selectable.

Comment: It won't let me use any local `.png` files either. They're all greyed-out in the selection dialog.

Comment: I've got an idea, might as well post it as an "answer" too... hold on a minute

Comment: Post your answer and I'll accept it; the problem was with the UI and it's weird paradigm. I'm supposed to select a *directory*, not a file. Once I do that, it works. Weird. However thanks for responding (and do provide an answer if you like).

Comment: Oh, from that selection box! Another place it greys out things, very similar. I noticed that mine's not looking recursively down through the selected directory either, maybe a setting or maybe it just doesn't do that. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the GUI for XFCE's Settings -> Desktop -> Background tab, if you select the "Style:" to None (drop-down box towards bottom right, by mouse in image) then it uses the solid color options just below, and greys out all the wallpaper images above:

[image]

Setting one of the other options like Centered, Scaled... will let you pick a background image:

[image]

(I ran into that problem when trying to get a solid color background with no image, it's not very clear!)

Comment: It's a pretty crazy setup but it does work once you figure out what it wants you to do.